# Utilizado AUTO_INCREMENT para criar números de ID

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou a usar AUTO_INCREMENT para adicionar automaticamente um ID sempre que crio uma nova coluna. No entanto quando limpo uma coluna, o número do ID continua a adicionar +1 em vez de começar de onde parou.

Como é que faço para que quando limpo uma coluna o número do ID seja o mesmo invés de adicionar +1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando utilizas auto increment, vai incrementar em todas as rows adicionadas, depois quando eliminas podes utilizar várias abordagens. Sendo todos os dados de uma vez, utiliza o truncate table que irá fazer reseed a esse valor. Ressalvo, no entanto que tipicamente dados não são eliminados, mas sim marcados como eliminandos com uma flag isDeleted por exemplo. Mas, se mesmo que queiras eliminar e manter a sequência dos ID's, podes fazer da seguinte forma:

**MySQL**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

**MS SQL**

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, reseed, value)
```

Comment: Já tinha visto a primeira opção (MySQL) e realmente deve ser o melhor que posso fazer, obrigado!